# How to add another same column from three or more tables in query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```sql
SELECT 
    material, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table1', sale, 0)) AS table1_sale, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table2', sale, 0)) AS table2_sale,
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table3', sale, 0)) AS table3_sale
FROM
    (SELECT material, sale, 'table1' AS source 
     FROM table1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT material, sale, 'table2'
     FROM table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT material, sale, 'table3'
     FROM table3) x
GROUP BY 
    material
ORDER BY 
    material;
```

This code is my answer, but I want show another same column of tables into the query table please help me

[image]

Comment: Just add `SUM(sale) AS Total` to the select list.

Comment: PLEAES SEE THE PICTURE I MENTION ALL OF THE COLUMN INTO THE QUERY EXCEPT ID HOW CAN I ADD ID OF ID OF 3 TABLE

Comment: Just like you added material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the totals column with `SUM(sale) AS Total`.

For the `id` column you must take care to add it to all the SELECT statements and also to the GROUP BY clause.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    material, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table1', sale, 0)) AS table1_sale, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table2', sale, 0)) AS table2_sale,
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table3', sale, 0)) AS table3_sale,
    SUM(sale) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT id, material, sale, 'table1' AS source
     FROM table1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, sale, 'table2'
     FROM table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, sale, 'table3'
     FROM table3) x
GROUP BY 
    id, material
ORDER BY 
    material;
```

Alternatively, you can select the 3 sales where each one of them returns the sale in turn for each table and the other two return 0.0.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    material, 
    SUM(sale1) AS table1_sale,
    SUM(sale2) AS table2_sale,
    SUM(sale3) AS table3_sale,
    SUM(sale1 + sale2 + sale3) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT id, material, sale AS sale1, 0.0  AS sale2, 0.0  AS sale3
     FROM table1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, 0.0  AS sale1, sale AS sale2, 0.0  AS sale3
     FROM table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, 0.0  AS sale1, 0.0  AS sale2, sale AS sale3
     FROM table3) x
GROUP BY 
    id, material
ORDER BY 
    material;
```

Comment: how can i update the query and edit some fields does it possible

Comment: The Access query designer is not able to work on UNION queries. You will have to switch to SQL view and do the edits in the SQL text.

Comment: so can you send me a SQL code ? how can i do your advice?– 
@Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Comment: Editing "some fields" is very vague. Are you looking for an [UPDATE query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-statement-microsoft-access-sql)?

Answer (score 1):

Here, we will add id column in all the "UNION ALL" tables. I assume id to be the unique id of the material. In the outer query we can add either MIN(id) or Max(id).

```
SELECT 
    material, 
    MAX(x.id) id,
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table1', sale, 0)) AS table1_sale, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table2', sale, 0)) AS table2_sale,
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table3', sale, 0)) AS table3_sale
FROM
    (SELECT id, material, sale, 'table1' AS source 
     FROM table1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, sale, 'table2'
     FROM table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, sale, 'table3'
     FROM table3) x
GROUP BY 
    material
ORDER BY 
    material;
```

OR, we can group by both id and material and avoid using MIN/MAX id in outer query.

```
SELECT 
    material, 
    id,
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table1', sale, 0)) AS table1_sale, 
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table2', sale, 0)) AS table2_sale,
    SUM(IIF(source = 'table3', sale, 0)) AS table3_sale
FROM
    (SELECT id, material, sale, 'table1' AS source 
     FROM table1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, sale, 'table2'
     FROM table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, material, sale, 'table3'
     FROM table3) x
GROUP BY 
    id, material
ORDER BY 
    id, material;
```